# RaycastHit to work only when hitting collider

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am making find a difference game. I made a ray that hits an image with collider and changes certain text property. Problem is that where ever i touch the screen it detects a ray, and changes the text. How can i solve that, i also unchecked Raycast Target for all other objects on screen.

```
public List<GameObject> hiddenObjects;
    public Text test;
    public Text click;    
    GameObject[] objekti;

    private RaycastHit2D result;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        //This is for a list that will fill with GameObjects 
        objects= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Slike");
        hiddenObjects = new List<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
        {
            hiddenObjects.Add(objects[i]);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Vector2 camRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            result = Physics2D.Raycast(camRay, (Input.GetTouch(0).position));
            if (result.collider.gameObject)
            {
                click.text = "CLICK";                
            }

            //This is supposed to delete 1 object at time as it is clicked on
            for (int j = 0; j < hiddenObjects.Count; j++)
            {
                if (hiddenObjects[j] = null)
                {
                    hiddenObjects.RemoveAt(j);
                }
            } 
            //Simple if statement if list is empty, print "Win"
            if (hiddenObjects.Count == 0)
            {
                test.text = "WIN";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided. I think in those code:

```
if (result.collider.gameObject)
{
    click.text = "CLICK";                
}
```

You need to identify the object that has been hit either by the name property or by comparing a tag.

Let's do it by name for simplicity.

In the left hand side menu in Unity A.K.A "Hierarchy" let's say the GameObject is called "ObjectToDetectHitOn" you would change the above code to:

```
if (result.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("ObjectToDetectHitOn"))
{
    click.text = "CLICK";                
}
```

This will not work if you Instantiate gameobject in code because they will then have (Clone) added to the end of the name. In this scenario you would have to use the .Contains() method of the String class.

The preferred method would be to actually add a tag to the GameObject, let's say you created a tag with the name "ObjectToDetectRay" and use the code like this:

```
if (result.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("ObjectToDetectRay"))
{
    click.text = "CLICK";                
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work or if it is unclear and I will try to explain further.

Comment: I used the tag method and it doesn't work. Is it maybe something with my ray declaration?

Comment: When you create a tag is doesn't add the tag straight away. You have to go back to the object and make sure it is added. Check that it definitely has a tag.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but it still doesn't work. Maybe it's something with my touch detection.